# SQL - Substraction using values from previous columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I  have a query which lists a country name ,total number of customers per country and number of active customers( they exist in the sales table).

I need a column where  the number of  inactive customers should be calculated ,but since one can't use  defined aliases in the same select statement ,I  got stuck

Here is the query:

```
SELECT  country_name , COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) AS TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS ,                                                                                  
COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id) AS NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 

FROM countries ctr JOIN customers cust
ON (cust.country_id = ctr.country_id) 
LEFT JOIN  sales sh 
ON (sh.cust_id =  cust.cust_id)

GROUP BY  country name
```

How should I approach this problem ?

Comment: you can subtract the 2 counts in the query.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desires results.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) -  COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id)  - Like this ?  I thought so , but SQLDeveloper says it's syntax error  and  wouldn't let me do it for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your approach, you would do:

```
SELECT ctr.country_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) AS TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id) AS NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 
       (COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) - COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id)) AS NUM_INACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 
FROM countries ctr JOIN
     customers cust
     ON cust.country_id = ctr.country_id LEFT JOIN
     sales sh 
     ON sh.cust_id =  cust.cust_id
GROUP BY ctr.country_name;
```

For performance, I would suggest doing an aggregation before the `join`:

```
SELECT ctr.country_name,
       COUNT(cust.cust_id) AS TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS, 
       COUNT(sh.cust_id) AS NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 
       (COUNT(cust.cust_id) - COUNT(sh.cust_id)) AS NUM_INACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 
FROM countries ctr JOIN
     customers cust
     ON cust.country_id = ctr.country_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT cust_id
      FROM sales sh 
     ) sh
     ON sh.cust_id =  cust.cust_id
GROUP BY country_name;
```

This removes the need for the `count(distinct)`.

Comment: Thank you , I've  actually reinstalled SQLDeveloper and now the substraction works fine , but  i didn't thought about doing the aggregation before join , thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery for this case :

```
SELECT country_name,TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS,NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS,
(TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS-ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS) AS INACTIVE_CUSTOMERS FROM (
SELECT  country_name , COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) AS TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS ,                                                                                  
COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id) AS NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS 
FROM countries ctr JOIN customers cust
ON (cust.country_id = ctr.country_id) 
LEFT JOIN  sales sh 
ON (sh.cust_id =  cust.cust_id)
GROUP BY  country name ) AS A
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query in an outer query; that will let you use the column aliases:

```
SELECT  t.*,
        TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS - NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS AS NUM_INACTIVE_CUSTOMERS
FROM    (
  SELECT  country_name,
          COUNT(DISTINCT cust.cust_id) AS TOTAL_NUM_CUSTOMERS,
          COUNT(DISTINCT sh.cust_id) AS NUM_ACTIVE_CUSTOMERS
  FROM    countries ctr
          JOIN customers cust
          ON (cust.country_id = ctr.country_id) 
          LEFT JOIN  sales sh 
          ON (sh.cust_id =  cust.cust_id)
  GROUP BY  country name
) t
```